# Comportamiento extraño en string.size()

Tags: c++

Tengo cierta tarea con C++ donde necesito trabajar con strings y tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Ingrese el mensaje: ";
    string Msg; cin >> Msg;
    size_t Size = Msg.size();
    cout << Size << endl;
}
```

Al compilar y ejecutar el codigo, no pasa ningún problema si asigno el valor directamente.

```
Msg = "Hola Mundo"; 
Size = Msg.size(); // El valor de size es correctamente 10

Msg = "312 123"; 
Size = Msg.size(); // El valor de size es 7.
```

El problema ocurre cuando asigno el valor a la variable `Msg` usando `cin`:

```
cin >> Msg; // Asumiremos que Msg tiene un valor: "123 321"
Size = Msg.size(); // Size es igual a 3
```

¿A qué se debe esto, no está `Size` supuesto a ser 7, si el mensaje introducido por teclado fuera `"123 321"` ?

**EDIT:** Lo mismo pasa con la función `length()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para no tener ese tipo de problemas mejor utiliza `getline`

```
getline(cin,Msg);
```

Ten en cuenta que `cin` deja de leer la entrada estándar al encontrar un espacio.

[Ver más (en inglés)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

[Ver más (español)](http://ejercicioscpp.blogspot.com.ar/2013/07/c-leer-caracteres-cadenas-de-caracteres.html)

Comment: Pero, precisamente por qué pasa eso?

Comment: porque por defecto cin utilizado de esa forma se detiene ante el primer espacio en blanco.

Comment: Solo ocurre con numeros, usando Dev-C++ me da la siguiente salida: `"1234 321"` : `4>3`

Answer (score 1):

Esto te sucede debido a que si leemos un string con **cin**, se deja de leer del buffer cuando se encuentra un espacio, por eso te aparece como longitud 3.
Si utilizas la función getline(), se leen líneas completas(hasta que se encuentra un '\n')

Recomendación: leer palabras o caracteres (cin),
leer lineas (getline)